# Bulma dropdown not closing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dropdown, bulma

I use bulma dropdown in my project. The dropdown works fine, but the problem is that when I add dropdowns in more than one colon with the backend, when one is open but the other is open, the first one is not closed and the dropdowns are overlapping.

If a class is assigned from a dropdown open state, `.is-active`, it does not delete the previous `.is-active` class when I want to open another dropdown.

How can I solve the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGMyF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sNTp.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get all dropdowns on the page that aren't hoverable.
  var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown:not(.is-hoverable)');

  if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
    // For each dropdown, add event handler to open on click.
    dropdowns.forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (!el.classList.contains("is-active")) {
          el.classList.toggle('is-active');
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    });

    // If user clicks outside dropdown, close it.
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      closeDropdowns();
    });
  }

  /*
   * Close dropdowns by removing `is-active` class.
   */
  function closeDropdowns() {
    dropdowns.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('is-active');
    });
  }

  // Close dropdowns if ESC pressed
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    let e = event || window.event;
    if (e.key === 'Esc' || e.key === 'Escape') {
      closeDropdowns();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown is-right ">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu3">
      <span><strong class="fw900">. . .</strong></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu3" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="">Sil</a>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="">Duzenle</a>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="">OnayDurumu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown is-right ">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu3">
      <span><strong class="fw900">. . .</strong></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu3" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="">Sil</a>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="">Duzenle</a>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="">OnayDurumu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get all dropdowns on the page that aren't hoverable.
  var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown:not(.is-hoverable)');

  if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
    // For each dropdown, add event handler to open on click.
    dropdowns.forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
        if (!el.classList.contains("is-active")) {
          el.classList.toggle('is-active');
          
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    });

    // If user clicks outside dropdown, close it.
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      closeDropdowns();
    });
  }

  /*
   * Close dropdowns by removing `is-active` class.
   */
  function closeDropdowns() {
    dropdowns.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('is-active');
    });
  }

  // Close dropdowns if ESC pressed
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    let e = event || window.event;
    if (e.key === 'Esc' || e.key === 'Escape') {
      closeDropdowns();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: is currently opening both of them at the same time; bad code. when I open one I want, the other closes